# Python: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I have written a little script in Python that I use to append text to a work log.  I have placed the script in a directory in my $PATH

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# import necessary modules
import sys
import os
import datetime


# main() function
def main():
  now = datetime.datetime.now()

  tmp = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])

  outfile = '/path/to/output/done.log'

  outstr = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + ' - ' + tmp + '\n'

  f=open(outfile,'a')
  f.write(outstr)
  f.close()

  # print sys.argv[0:1]
  print 'Adding ' + outstr

# Call main()
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

When I run the script as in example 1, I get an error.

Example 1:

```
host:scripts user$ done this is a test
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
```

If I run the script as in example 2, it behaves as expected.

Example 2:

```
host:scripts user$ python done this is a test
Adding 2012-11-15 09:57:44 - this is a test
```

How do I get this to work in the first example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`done` is a bash keyword, so can't be used in certain places like "the place Bash expects a command name". You could use `./done` (or `/path/to/done`, or `python /path/to/done`), or re-name the command.

Comment: Very nice!   If I rename the script to "cow" it works perfectly...  now to find a verb that means complete...